# Mock method in abstract class that inherit abstract class

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a service that extends abstract class in my spring-boot project

```
public class TestService extends AbstractTest1Service {
// some methods
}

public abstract class AbstractTest1Service extends AbstractTest2Service {

    public String doSomething() {
        return writeText();
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractTest2Service {

    String writeText() {
        return "text";
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mock `writeText()` method when i want to test `TestService`:

Comment: you want to test TestService class ?

Comment: I don't see why this should not be possible

Comment: yes i want to test TestService.class which use doSomething() method that i want to mock to return different values

Comment: Why cannot you just mock `doSomething`? Btw I think you can easily mock `writeText` as usual. You can mock `writeText` and then `doSomething` to return value, which is produced by mocked `writeText`

Comment: doSomething is package-private, i made mistake in my example code

Comment: Why would you want to mock it? First, you don't mock tested classes. Second, it has a fixed behavior so you can just use that.

Comment: There is no much point in mocking package-private/private methods. But sometimes you need it. For this you can use Powermock framework

Answer (score 0):

Your `TestService` class:

```java
public class TestService extends AbstractTest1Service {
    AbstractTest2Service abstractTest2Service;

    public String doSomething() {
        abstractTest2Service.writeText();
        System.out.println("Passed!");
        return "All Checked";
    }
}
```

---

Your `TestServiceTest` class should be like:

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    TestService testService;

    @Mock
    AbstractTest2Service abstractTest2Service;

    @Test
    public void testService(){
        Assert.assertEquals("All Checked",testService.doSomething());
    }
}
```

> **Note:** Do not use `@Spy` instead of `@Mock` , Spy will try to check the actual implementation of the abstract class methods which is not
>   there , so your test will be ignored. Just use `@Mock`.

Using @Spy will give error:

> Cannot instantiate a `@Spy` for '`abstractTest2Service`' field. You
>   haven't provided the instance for spying at field declaration so I
>   tried to construct the instance. However, I failed because: the type
>   '`AbstractTest2Service` is an abstract class.